# Битая аватарка автора в режиме просмотра списка вопросов

Tags: дефект, статус-проверка, imgur, аватар-пользователя

Есть участник: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/u/468441/

И его вопрос: [Как в шаблонизаторе Jinja правильно вывести данные в шаблон (несколько фотографий к одной машине)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1521328/)

Если увидеть вопрос в списке вопросов то это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но пользователь выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что стало с аватаром?

Comment: Ещё раз предложу вам сделать репорт по проблеме на MSE. С меткой `[imgur]` должны принять.

Comment: У меня похожая ситуация сегодня была. Почистил кеш и cookie - всё вернулось на свои места.

Comment: @Зонтик конкретно обозначенной проблемы это касается? Иконка становится нормальной? Если нет, то это не тот случай.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ странно... конкретно этот аватар до сех пор не отображается... Так что чистка кеша не поможет решить проблему.

Comment: Иногда это работает как цензура) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1523722

Answer (score 5):

Соглашусь с коллегой модератором, что бага не на стороне Stack Overflow, однако, сервис imgur в части взаимодействия с SO оплачивается компанией и проблемы пользователей SO по вопросам обслуживания картинок вполне себе могут эскалироваться со стороны SO.

Я повесил метку [статус-проверка](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0), это должно привести к появлению тикета, видимого во внутреннем баг-трекере SO. Но ничто не мешает вам перепостить баг на MSE. Там больше пользователей с разных сайтов, которые могли сталкиваться с подобными же проблемами и подтвердить их существование.

Пока выглядит так, что надо как-то пнуть imgur, чтобы они перегенерили мини-картинку для данного конкретного участника.

Comment: На MSE что-то похожее уже есть: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166575/

Comment: @wchistow кстати, а участник nchistov (автор вопроса) вам знаком?

Comment: Да. (ещё 7 символов)

Comment: @wchistow передавайте ему привет!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ок, передал :)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с серой завесой (именно с серой завесой, а не со значком [image: значок картинки], которая решается путём чистки кеша и cookies) не особо часто встречается. **Убрать серую завесу на самом деле очень просто: пользователю нужно просто перезагрузить свой аватар** (ну то есть загрузить его заново).

Поскольку проблема на стороне imgur, искоренить этот баг будет довольно сложно. **Пока придётся довольствоваться текущим вариантом решения**.

Постить баг на MSE, как предлагал @αλεχολυτ **смысла нет**. Потому что уже [постили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166575/why-is-there-a-peeking-duck-in-my-profile-pic), ещё в 2013. А новый баг-репост закроют как дубль, как [этот](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238863/) или [этот](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176257/) например.